# How do I open a file as an admin using NSIS

Tags: installation, admin, nsis

I am opening a file using the installer script nsis and i need to open it as an admin in order for it to run properly, but i cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

currently my open code looks like this:

```
FileOpen $4 "$R0" w
FileRead $4 $1
FileClose $4
```

it opens it but as a regular user and i need it to be as an admin.  is there a way to do this?? thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot open a file as a different user in a normal application. If you need this kind of power the whole installer probably needs [to run elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735349/3501):

```
Outfile RequireAdmin.exe
RequestExecutionLevel admin ;Require admin rights on NT6+ (When UAC is turned on)

!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
UserInfo::GetAccountType
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights on NT4+
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Page InstFile

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: That's true: one process has only one security token during its entire life. So either a process has administrator privileges or it doesn't have them.

Comment: I am  trying to get the same effect as right clicking on the file and choosing run as administrator.