# Installer is ignoring WriteRegStr (trying to add application to Win Startup)

Tags: windows-7, registry, nsis

I'm installing an app to a Windows 7 machine (my app is targeting one specific device) and I'm trying to get it to run on OS startup/login.

It's a Silverlight OOB app, I thought this might have been a problem, but I tested it with Notepad and it still doesn't work.

I followed the example [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Running_a_.exe_file_on_Windows_Start):

```
!include "MUI.nsh"

Name "Tech Drive Installer"
OutFile "techdrive_setup.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\Tech Drive"

RequestExecutionLevel admin
ShowInstDetails show

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    SetOverwrite ifnewer

    File "TechDrive.xap"
    ExecWait '"$PROGRAMFILES\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" /install:"$INSTDIR\TechDrive.xap" /origin:"http://localhost/TechDrive.xap" /shortcut:desktop'

    WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" "TechDrive" '"$PROGRAMFILES\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" 3388701632.localhost'
SectionEnd
```

Why wouldn't this be working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WriteRegStr call worked fine on this 32-bit Win7 machine. When writing to HKLM you should [make sure you are admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732019/how-do-you-request-administrator-permissions-using-nsis/8735349#8735349).

If you are using a 64-bit OS you will end up writing to the [WOW64 part of the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097). In NSIS you can control this with the `SetRegView` instruction but either Run key should work.

You could use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to verify that the value was added correctly or monitor it directly with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  If it still fails to start I would double check the path to make sure it is correct. (Programs that run at startup are not allowed to require administrator rights either)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't know about the separate 32/64bit registry sections. That's the problem, because it worked on my 32bit tablet PC.