# System32\xyz folder not found when running batch during VS build event

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd, post-build-event

When running a batch as a post-build event from VS, some of my folders become invisible to the command line. The error log and output logs are nondescript.

In my subsequent batch, I cannot access SCP (System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe)

Build event:

```
IF NOT DEFINED PUBLISHING (
set PUBLISHING ='ON'
call "$(ProjectDir)Publish.bat"
PUBLISHING=
)
```

Changing `call` to `start`, a cmd window pops up and I have checked my variables and poked around in the environment.

- Username is correct
- The window is running as Admin (for other reasons)
- `PATH` is fine (and shouldn't have anything to do with `cd` to begin with)

When poking around, if I try to change directories, it claims that `System32\OpenSSH` doesn't exist!
<sub>(Absolute path truncated)</sub>

What can System folders to not be accessible to an admin?

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details). There are two `%SystemRoot%\System32` directories. Which one is used depends on execution environment, 32 or 64 bit environment.

Comment: @Mofi Thank you for the tip! If you happen to know how to choose the execution environment, that would make for a great answer I think! If not, I'll figure it out and post it myself later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Mofi's comment,

> Please read the Microsoft documentation about [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details). There are two %SystemRoot%\System32 directories. Which one is used depends on execution environment, 32 or 64 bit environment.

it was easy to determine that the `cmd` being used by VS was x86 and thus does not have access to the same `System32` folder. In order to use `OpenSSH\SCP`, I needed to call the the x64 version of cmd.

For that, we can also refer to Mofi's [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488948/3838167).

The result is something like this:
<sub>Note: Here we start a new cmd window because publish needs user input. A regular "call" should be fine too</sub>

```
IF NOT DEFINED PUBLISHING (
set PUBLISHING='ON'
:: We know we are currently running x86, so call other cmd without checking version
start %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe /C call "$(ProjectDir)Publish.bat" 
PUBLISHING=
::Needed to add for build to 'succeed', not in original script post
exit /b 0 
)
```