# NSIS WriteRegSTR or WriteRegDword

Tags: nsis

I am trying to write to the reg and cant seem to find the correct way.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "XboxStat" '"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Xbox 360 Accessories\\XboxStat.exe\" silentrun'
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "Hyperspin" "D:\\Arcade\\Hyperspin.exe\"
```

I have tried:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "Hyperspin" "D:\\Arcade\\Hyperspin.exe\"
WriteRegDWORD HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "Hyperspin" "D:\\Arcade\\Hyperspin.exe\"
WriteRegStr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "Hyperspin" "D:\\Arcade\\Hyperspin.exe\"
WriteRegDWORD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "Hyperspin" "D:\\Arcade\\Hyperspin.exe\"
```

But nothing ever shows up in reg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your installer needs to [run as a elevated administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735349/3501) to write to HKLM. Add `RequestExecutionLevel Admin` to your script.

2) On 64-bit Windows there are [two different views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx) of the registry and by default 32-bit applications write to the `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` key in the "real" registry you see in RegEdit. Use [`SetRegView`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SetRegView) in NSIS to write to the 64-bit registry.

Comment: Thank you so much I was scratching my head for hours trying to figure that out and all i needed was SetRegView. :)