# NSIS executing a system command

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to create a scheduled task with privileges in my NSIS script.

Using this command:

```
schtasks /create /ru "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SC ONSTART /RL "HIGHEST" /TR "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MyProgram.exe" /tn MyProgram.Kickstart
```

From cmd.exe with privileges I managed to do it, but now I need to let the NSIS script doing it.
Reading the documentation and the internet I've found this command:

```
;   ........
Section
    ExecShell "runas" "myprogram.bat"
SectionEnd
;   ........
```

where "myprogram.bat" is the bat containing the command, but I've also tried to put the schtasks in it.
Currently it seems that no batch runs, even if I have this log:

```
Processing script file: "C:\Foo\prova.nsis"
OutFile: "C:\Foo\testnsis.exe"
Section: "TestFST"
ExecShell: runas: "C:\Foo\kickstart.bat" "" 
SectionEnd
```

if I add 2> kickstart.log in bat and I execute it outside NSIS, i get the log filled as expected, but nothing from the script.

Also consider that, for sake of simplicity and testing purposes, I've wrote a very basic script launched from powershell:

```
# Powershell
makensis.exe /O"C:\Foo\prova.log" "C:\Foo\prova.nsis"

; NSIS
OutFile "C:\Foo\testnsis.exe"

Section TestFST
    ExecShell "runas" "C:\Foo\kickstart.bat"
SectionEnd
```

and I might missing something, since I'm completely new to this.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use full paths everywhere. When elevating the current directory is often set to the system32 directory and `2> kickstart.log` would write there.

ExecShell works fine for me:

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\Test.cmd" w
FileWrite $0 "@echo off$\r$\n"
FileWrite $0 "echo Hello World$\r$\n"
FileWrite $0 'call whoami /groups | find "1-5-32-544"$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 'echo Log test string > "%temp%\test.log"$\r$\n'
FileWrite $0 "ping -n 42 localhost > nul$\r$\n"
FileClose $0
ExecShell "runas" "$PluginsDir\Test.cmd"
SectionEnd
```

That being said, the runas verb has some issues and if you know you are always going to perform elevated tasks then [your installer should also request elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735349/3501) (`RequestExecutionLevel Admin`).

Comment: I'm not completely sure about it, but I think that the main installer has full privileges.

Comment: If the installer is elevated (UAC dialog) then you don't need "runas" at all in the script.

Comment: Well, I added the function as mentioned in the question that you linked, modified the 2> path, but I still get no error and no result. Thi is little disappointing (BTW I've already read your answers)

Comment: What happens if you copy my code from this answer, do you see Hello World in the terminal?

Comment: You know, sometimes one simply needs some (long) vacations... Accepted.